# 4 dimensional array of zeros in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make an 4 dimensional array of zeros in python. 
I know how to do this for a square array but I want the lists to have different lengths.

Right now I use this:

```
numpy.zeros((200,)*4)
```

Which gives them all length 200 but I would like to have lengths `200,20,100,20` because now I have a lot of zeros in my array that I don't use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `np.full`:

```
>>> np.full((200,20,10,20), 0)
```

> **numpy.full**
>
> Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with fill_value.

Example :

```
>>> np.full((1,3,2,4), 0)
array([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass more than one arg to shape:

> shape : int or sequence of ints
>   Shape of the new array, e.g., (2, 3) or 2.

```
In [26]: arr = np.zeros((200, 20, 10, 20))

In [27]: arr.shape
Out[27]: (200, 20, 10, 20)
```

It also seems a lot more efficient when you have large dimensions:

```
In [43]: timeit arr = np.full((200, 100, 100, 100),0)
1 loops, best of 3: 232 ms per loop

In [44]: timeit arr = np.zeros((200, 100, 100, 100))
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop
In [45]: timeit arr = np.zeros((500, 100, 100, 100))
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 µs per loop    
In [46]: timeit arr = np.full((500, 100, 100, 100),0)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.19 s per loop
```

Comment: I didn't know you could pass args to shape.  Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python v. 3.50, using the `np.full` command returns

`FutureWarning: in the future, full((1, 3, 2, 4), 0) will return an array of dtype('int32')`.

Based on this, I'd plug @Padriac's answer.  Both work for now, though!